# how can I get same Ip count group by name?

Tags: mysql

how can I get same Ip count group by name ?

```
select 
name,count(*) as count 
from p 
group by name
```

[image]

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `p`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `p`;
CREATE TABLE `p` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of p
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('1', 'jimmy', '1.1.1.1');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('2', 'jimmy', '1.1.1.2');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('3', 'tina', '1.1.1.1');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('4', 'tina', '1.2.3.4');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('6', 'jimmy', '1.1.1.1');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('7', 'jimmy', '1.1.1.3');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('8', 'darcy', '1.1.1.1');
INSERT INTO `p` VALUES ('9', 'darcy', '1.2.1.2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name,
       count(*) as count,
       count(*) - (count(*) - count(distinct ip)) as same_ip_count
from p 
group by name
```

Comment: seems not the same result with my photo

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
select 
name,
(select count(*) from p as t_detail where t1.ip = t_detail.ip and t1.name = t_detail.name) AS count
from p as t1
group by name
```